# How to create autocommand for the buffer that is opened with the :registers command

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to create an autocommand for the buffer that is opened when the `:registers` command is issued (or by any shortcut or command that could be mapped for showing it). I would like to color some lines differently (but this is not the problem). **The problem is I have no idea how to detect this event**.

I have created this snippet for debugging (prints to buffer with id 3, the buffer name and buffer id) based on all events related to buffers I can think of, and for the registers buffer it does nothing...

```
function EchoBuf()
  call appendbufline(3, 1, bufname())
  call appendbufline(3, 2, bufnr("%"))
endfunction

autocmd WinEnter,BufAdd,BufNew,BufRead,BufEnter * call EchoBuf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:registers` doesn't open a buffer, it opens `:help pager`, which doesn't trigger any event.

But you could hack something with the help of `:help CmdlineLeave` and `:help getcmdline()`:

```
function! DoSomethingWhenIWantToLookAtMyRegisters()
    if getcmdline() =~ '^reg'
        echomsg 'Here is the list of registers and their content'
    endif
endfunction

augroup MyStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineLeave * call DoSomethingWhenIWantToLookAtMyRegisters()
augroup END
```

As for coloring lines in `:registers`, you would be better off populating a buffer yourself with the data how you want it to be laid out and assign it your own syntax.

Comment: but, I guess you can't really change the highlights for that pager window, right?